# Jacobian of a diffeomorphism

Tags: functions, manifolds, determinant

Let $U,V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open. Let $\alpha:U \to V$ be a smooth homeomorphism. Furthermore, assume that $\mathcal{J}_{\alpha}(\mathbf{x})$ (the Jacobian matrix) has rank $n$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in U$.

$\ $

Is it true that $\det\left( \mathcal{J}_{\alpha}(\mathbf{x}) \right) \neq 0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in U$?

$\ $

If so, how do I prove this. If not, why not?

Comment: This is really a linear algebra question, as full rank is equivalent to having a nonzero determinant.

Comment: This was a stupid oversight on my part. Thank you! Which theorem in particular does this result belong to?

Comment: Once one has chosen a basis, this is part of what's sometimes called the Invertible Matrix Theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

if  an $n\times n$ matrix has rank $n$ that it is invertible (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem)) so its determinant in not null.